# Interpretation of chi-squared on proportion

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, proportion

I have this array:

| name | responsive | not responsive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 16 | 95 |
| y | 5 | 83 |

I am trying to compare the proportion of `X_`responsive with `Y_`responsive but the classic `z-`test of proportions can't be used here because my data is not normally distributed. I have used a chi-square test of proportions instead but I'm not sure what the output means in terms of my table.

```
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as ssp
(chi2, p, arr) = ssp.proportions_chisquare(count = df_obs.non_response, nobs = df_obs.sum(axis = 1))
print((chi2, p))
```

```
Chi2 = 3.96557520785049
p = 0.046439653061788856
```

I know it is significant but I'm not sure what is this is interpreted as.

Comment: You have binary variables, so you will never have normal data. Why do you think the z-test is inappropriate? // The $\chi^2$ test is a fine test to use, whether you think th z-test is appropriate or not. What confuses you about the output?

Comment: What exactly the chi-square is revealing here. Is it just that there is a relationship between name and responsiveness?
- if so, how can i determine the direction? whether  is more responsive or y is more responsive?

Comment: It will help if you go back to the z-test to explain why you think it does not apply and what you would get out of it if it did apply.

Comment: Yes with the z-test of two proportions the null hypothesis that the two proportions are equally responsive is rejected. However the test statistic gives me a direction which tells me which is more responsive than the other. How do I determine which variable is most responsive in  chi-square? or is this inferred from the raw data

Comment: Yes, you determine that from the raw data. Again, though, why do you think the z-test does not apply?

Comment: I ran a shapiro wilks test on the X and Y values, for which the raw data is continuous and numerical. We used these values to categorise them into X and Y.
Once they become binary, does it not matter about the normality?

Comment: Once they become binary, they *cannot* be normal. Normal distributions can take any real value, and binary distributions only take two values (quite a lot less than $\infty$). The bigger issue, though, is that you have destroyed information by binning your variables. This may warrant a separate question, but what were your starting $X$ and $Y$, and what question(s) do you want to use $X$ and $Y$ to answer?

Comment: X and Y had many values from -1 to 1. Of which, any that were X>0.4 were classified as  one variabile and any Y>0.5 classified as another variable. I did this to see if values that were classified as X and Y were different in terms of responsiveness. My question does not warrant any investigation into X<0.4. 
The z-test may be better because it looks at the proportions of x>0.4 / all x-values?

Comment: You should post a separate question about your binning of the raw data. Perhaps it makes sense for your task, but it usually destroys information.

Comment: Because you used the $X$ and $Y$ values to determine the binning, the p-value no longer is correct.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919 for an example of what can go wrong.

Comment: Thank you both! this was helpful! I assume I run into the same problems if i keep my dichotomised variables and run the z-test?

Comment: The two tailed z-test and the chi-squared are *exactly the same test*, with *exactly the same assumptions*.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment:* Illustration of @Glen-b's Comment about the equivalence of `prop.test` and `chisq.test` for your data.

The two procedures give exactly the same P-value:

```
prop.test(c(16,5), c(111,88))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(16, 5) out of c(111, 88)
X-squared = 3.0944, df = 1, p-value = 0.07856
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.004154855  0.178806780
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.14414414 0.05681818 

TBL = rbind(c(16,5),c(95,83))
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 3.0944, df = 1, p-value = 0.07856
```

They are also the same if the continuity correction is not used.

```
prop.test(c(16,5), c(111,88), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.04643965
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.04643965
```

However, there are several versions of the test for equality of two binomial proportions. Some versions
use $H_0$ to argue for using a pooled sample proportion
$\hat p = \frac{x_1+x_2}{n_1+n_2}$ to get the standard error for $\hat p_1 - \hat p_2$ and some use separate
estimates $\hat p_i = x_i/n_i$ for this purpose. Also, various computer programs use different kinds of continuity corrections.

Also, if counts are too small for an accurate P-value in `chisq.test`, then R allows the option to simulate a more accurate P-value. (Simulation is not supported for `prop.test`.)

Finally, the Fisher Exact Test can give a different P-value than any of the above.

```
fisher.test(TBL)$p.val
[1] 0.06220786
```

Simulated p-values in `chisq.test` tend to be close to the Fisher p-value, especially if you use more than the default number of
iterations to simulate.

*Table with small counts:*

```
TAB = rbind(c(40, 3), c(60, 7));  TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   40    3
[2,]   60    7

chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB
X-squared = 0.077317, df = 1, p-value = 0.781

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 0.38181, df = NA, p-value = 0.7276
```

More iterations:

```
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T, B = 5000)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 7000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 0.38181, df = NA, p-value = 0.744

fisher.test(TAB)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TAB
p-value = 0.7374
alternative hypothesis: 
 true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3292961 9.8349592
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.549608
```